# How to 'untar()' this file?

Tags: r

I am trying to `untar()` a file wit pretrained wordembeddings that I found [here](http://www.clips.uantwerpen.be/dutchembeddings/combined-320.tar.gz), through [this](https://github.com/clips/dutchembeddings) site.

When I use the function like this:

```
pretrained <- untar("combined-320.tar.gz")
```

This is the result:

```
Warning message:
In untar("combined-320.tar.gz") :
  ‘tar.exe -xf "combined-320.tar.gz"’ returned error code 127
```

What could be going wrong here? Could there be a solution for R?

I have a windows 10 machine.

Comment: As far as I know error code 127 means that the command is not found in your path, at least in linux. Maybe you can force it to use the internal implementation by using `pretrained <- untar("combined-320.tar.gz", tar = "internal")`.

Comment: @ricoderks, thanks for the suggestion. It didn't work. There is no error anymore, but it returnd an empty object `NULL`. I am wondering now if the problem is caused by the fact that I use a windows 10 machine.

Comment: I think the issue is that you have a `tar.gz` instead of a `tar`  file. The tar file is also gzipped. `pretrained <- untar("combined-320.tar.gz", tar = "internal", compression = "gzip")`. Sorry, I missed this the first time.

Comment: And I "missed" it as well. But now I undestand things. thanks. However, your solution gives this error: `unused argument (compression = "gzip")`

Comment: @ricoderks, If you replace `compression` with `compressed` it wourld be better I guess. But it still gives an error.

Comment: sorry you're right. I was looking in the help of `tar` instead of `untar`. What is the error now?

Comment: it says: `argument 'compressed' is ignored for the internal method`

Comment: On my machine this is only a warning and the file is unpacked.

Comment: there is a pretrained object, but it is empty in my case. But if it works for you, then something else goes wrong. I will do some research again.

Comment: If the unpacking succeeds it should contain a zero `0L`.

Comment: Thanks, you are right! I will accept this as an aswer if you please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no tar/untar is installed you can use the internal one from R, add the `tar` parameter to `untar`

```
pretrained <- untar("combined-320.tar.gz", tar = "internal")
```

If the unpacking is successful pretained will contain a zero `0L`.

Cheers, Rico